# IntelliJ cannot find maven-war-plugin

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml, maven-war-plugin

It gives me this error in pom

[image]

The plugin is correctly available in m2 folder

[image]

other libraries are also recognized well, and the plugin is available in server...

[image]

I've tried to invalidate & restart and other tricks on the web, but it seems not to work.

Comment: Have you tried to build on plain command your project? does that work without any issue?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `.lastUpdated` files and run [Maven Sync](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven-projects-tool-window.html) (the icon with circular arrows).

Comment: where are lastupdated files?

Comment: In your Maven Local repository, judging by the screenshots. Should be: ~\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-war-plugin\3.4.0

Comment: it doesn't works